# How can I get rid of these elif statements to write cleaner code? or other clean code suggestions, thank you

Tags: python, code-cleanup

```
nameoffile = input('File name: ')

filename = nameoffile.lower()

if '.gif' in filename:
    print('image/gif')
elif '.jpg' in filename:
    print('image/jpeg')
elif '.jpeg' in filename:
    print('image/jpeg')
elif '.png' in filename:
    print('image/png')
elif '.pdf' in filename:
    print('application/pdf')
elif '.txt' in filename:
    print('text/plain')
elif '.zip' in filename:
    print('application/zip')
else:
    print('application/octet-stream')
```

Comment: You can use a case statement.

Comment: Honestly? Theres nothing wrong with that code. Trying to make "clean code" often just makes it harder to read and understand. But you could use a dictionary as a switch case maybe.

Comment: If you are using python3.10 you can use [`match...case`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-634-structural-pattern-matching) but it's also simply an elegant `if-elif` way. there's no other way round as such

Comment: you can get the characters after the last ```'.'``` with ```filename[filename.rfind('.'):]```

Comment: this won't make your code "cleaner" but if you find yourself writing a ton of if statements you'd rather have dynamically checked, create a dict. keys of the dict are values you search for, values are the return if that value exist.

Comment: I'll also add that you probably want `filename.endswith("...")` rather than your current code.  `mary.gift.jpeg` will incorrectly print out `image/gif` in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dict to map keys to functions or values

```py
def check_file_ext(fileName):
  
  file_ext_dict = {
    "zip": "image/gif",
    "png": "image/png",
    ...
  }
  file_type = fileName.split(".")[-1]
  return file_ext_dict[file_type] # might want to try catch incase file extension isn't in your dict
```

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, you may find the [mimetypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html#mimetypes.guess_type) module helpful (part of the standard library since Python 3.2):

```
>>> import mimetypes
>>> mimetypes.guess_type("blah.txt")
('text/plain', None)
>>> mimetypes.guess_type("thing.png")
('image/png', None)
>>> mimetypes.guess_type("important.pdf")
('application/pdf', None)
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically when you have a bunch of if statements you want to use a dictionary.

I would split the string on "." and get the last element for the key.

```
filetype = filename.split(".")[-1]

print(dictionary[filetype]) #dictionary mapping key to string you want to print
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rfind` to find the characters after the last `'.'` and then see if they are in the a dictionary with the file types as keys and what you want as values:

```
dct = {'.gif': 'image/gif', '.jpg': 'image/jpeg', '.jpeg': 'image/jpeg',
       '.png': 'image/png', '.pdf': 'application/pdf', '.txt': 'text/plain', 
       '.zip': 'application/zip'}
if (n:=filename[filename.rfind('.'):]) in dct:
    print(f"{dct[n]}")
else:
    print('application/octet-stream')
```

Answer (score 0):

Nin17's is probably better but I just have a soft spot for list comprehension:

```py
ext = ['.gif', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.pdf', '.txt', '.zip']
description = ['image/gif', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'application/pdf', 
               'text/plain', 'application/zip']

filename = "test.jpg"

try:
    final = [y for x,y in zip(ext, description) if x in filename][0]
except:
    final = 'application/octet-stream'
print(final)
```

Output

```
image/jpg
```